# Different AVL trees from a single Binary search tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am confused about whether we can generate more than one AVL tree from a given BST.

I have tried to do so and I'm getting an answer, but I don't know whether it is right or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly. Consider the following BST:

```
       [4]
       /
     [3]
     /
   [2]
   /
 [1]
```

It can be reorganized into at least 2 different trees which are correct AVLs:

```
#1:             #2:
     [3]             [2]
    /   \           /   \
 [1]     [4]     [1]     [4]
   \                     /
   [2]                 [3]
```

Comment: Only 2? Can't we get more than 2 different types of AVL tree for a single BST?

Comment: @SmitkumarRathod Sure, in general the number of potential AVLs is not limited to 2. However, you asked if it was possible to generate more than one, so I came up with the simplest more-than-one example =)